# Laravel 7: User Profile causing bug when uploading img and bio description

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

In a laravel 7 app I'm working on a feature where a user can upload their image profile and bio description. A problem that I'm facing is that there are certain cases when a user sets their profile image, the bio description would be gone. For example: If a user set their profile img and puts a description, but if the user sets another img then the description would be gone. Not quite sure what's the bugs that's causing it. (I'm using bootstrap modal for the user to edit their profile.)

controller.php

```
public function modalEditPost(Request $request)
{
        $user = Auth::user();
        $avatarName = "";
        $userBio = "";
        $request->validate([
            'bio' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($request->has('bio')) {

            $userBio = $request->bio;
            $user->bio = $userBio;
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

            if ($request->file('image')->isValid()) {

                $extension = $request->image->extension();

                $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.$extension;

                $request->image->move(public_path('/uploads/avatars'), $avatarName);

                $user->avatar = $avatarName;
            }
        }

        $user->save();

        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully edited your bio.')
            ->with('bio', $userBio)
            ->with('image', $avatarName);

}
```

index.blade.php

```
@include('partials.popup')
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card card-user">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <div class="author">
                            <div class="block block-one"></div>
                            <div class="block block-two"></div>
                            <div class="block block-three"></div>
                            <div class="block block-four"></div>
                            <img class = "avatar" src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar}}" alt="">
                            <h4 class="title">{{ auth()->user()->first_name }} {{ auth()->user()->last_name }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-description">
                            {{ Auth::user()->bio }}
                        </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success"
                                style="cursor: pointer"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#popupModal">{{ __('Edit Profile') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

popup.blade.php

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <!-- (Image upload) Start -->
                @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @endif

                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <!-- (Image upload) Start -->
                <form action="{{ route('modal.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p>Change Bio</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                           <input type="text" style="color:black" name="bio" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- (Image upload) End -->
            </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Does your bio passed to your controller?

Comment: @SokChanty I believe so...what do you mean specifically by that?